Draw dimension in tkz-euclide using dim without drawing Segment
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={$\SI{0.5}{m}$,-1.5cm,above=1mm,sloped,font=\normalsize,fill=white,inner sep=1mm},
dim style/.append style={black, semithick}](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


How to draw dim line without drawing line segment?

Can you give a rough idea of exactly what you want? Do you want to remove the vertical lines? It is not very clear from your post; a rough figure would help to clarify.

to remove horizontal line drawn by \tkzDrawSegment

You can omit the actual line segment with draw=none option.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={$\SI{0.5}{m}$,-1.5cm,above=1mm,sloped,font=\normalsize,fill=white,inner sep=1mm},
dim style/.append style={blue, semithick},draw=none](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


